# how to control width and height of child div?

Tags: jquery, css

hi i have a div `bat` with

```
#bat{
     width:50%;
     height:50%;
     }
```

html

```
<div id="bat">dynamic div will occur</div>
```

when dynamic div are placed if the content is larger than `#bat` width and height those content are overflowing.i can hide that using overflow hidden in `#bat` but i don't want it to be that way.
i want dynamic div to fit into `#bat`.thought of jquery child selector and then control them giving width and height to dynamic div.i don't know to select dynamically. can anybody help?

Comment: give them fluid width and height as well.

Comment: #bat width should be 50%

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/LWAjR/1/ i want the text box to place inside the #bat div

Comment: Than why are you giving #dynamic a fixed width?

Comment: i think i conveyed it wrongly. Dynamically means dynamically changeable div.one time it might be `#one{width:600px;height:600px;}` other time `#two{width:300px;height:300px;}` i don't know what id or class will it have.if i know that i can control it right

Comment: The moment you're manually defining a block element to be 600px wide, you can't make it break out of the blue. You're going the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

if you want to give your child div dynamic space then your parent div must have the appropriate space. if your parent div don't have enough space then it will overflow.

So you have to give your parent #bat a minimum and maximum height and width. That can be done by CSS you don't need Jquery selector for that.

you can give

min-height: 
max-height:
min-width:
max-width:

so your content will be remained in this div only there will not be any overflow until your max height reached.

Comment: what it reached maximum height and width.then we have to define size for dynamic div right.here i know the name but in action i will not know the name.if i know the name i can control it.this why am asking jquery slector

Answer (score 0):

You should use min-width/height instead.

```
#bat {
     min-width:50%;
     min-height:50%;
}
```

Edit :

The problem is you were setting the width/height on your dynamic content, you can't do that.

http://jsfiddle.net/LWAjR/4/

Comment: dynamic div is bigger than #bat and it is overflowing i want to control that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
display:block;
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? A div would have those styles by default

Comment: I would like you sugest use firefox- inspect element - and try to change your css value..that will help you ti adjust div widht and height..firefix shows you instance change when you made changes in css.. Hope you will get you solution - happy coding